# I get an error when I launch Blender

Tags: scripting, linux

I have installed compressed package from website, but when I executed the code `./blender` from Ubuntu on a cloud server, ref error occurs.

```
Unable to open a display 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked the contents of the environment variable `DISPLAY` with the command `echo $DISPLAY` on the terminal but it displays nothing:

[image]

The following is the output when running `./blender`:

[image]

Comment: what output do you get when running `echo $DISPLAY`? can you also include a screenshot of your terminal window

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to run blender,but I don't know how to run it correctly.

Comment: @STRUGGLE you are root in the screenshot, don't run as root. run as user. if you are a user what does `echo $DISPLAY` output? still empty? Try running `setenv DISPLAY :0.0; export DISPLAY`

Comment: Oh you are running blender from another server. You need to enable `X11 Forwarding` look here how to configure https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Comment: @Harry McKenzie But I was on a cloud server and I was to be root,I just can not change to user.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie this cloud server could not connect my computer through SSH.

Comment: so you tried doing an `ssh` to the cloud server with your client computer but the connection was refused? What is the error when doing `ssh` to the server? So that is why you logged directly in the server computer and ran blender from the server computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [`X11 Forwarding`](https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11035-how-to-use-x11-forwarding.html) in order to run graphical applications from a server.

> X11 forwarding is a mechanism that allows a user to start up remote applications, and then forward the application display to their local machine. It enables you to run GUIs from a local server. It’s essentially remote desktop software that looks better on your screen and is easier to work with.

Check this thread on how to configure this [How to forward X over SSH to run graphics applications remotely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely)